# CAS credentials bad

Tags: spring-security, cas

A help please

I have a problem when I want to use the CAS authentication, the error is invalid credentials, this shows me what the log

Browser

```
Estado HTTP 401 - Authentication Failed: Bad credential`s
```

Log CAS

```
ServiceValidateController [ERROR] TicketException generating ticket for: [callbackUrl: https://localhost:8443/receptor]
```

Thanks for your time

```
 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: unnamed; URL [https://geo.org.bo:443/geonetwork/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=ST-2-dLgdARnZdtPHWZa9krt9-cas]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'cas'
 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Successfully completed request
 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] DispatcherServlet with name 'cas' determining Last-Modified value for [/cas/serviceValidate]
 SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Mapping [/serviceValidate] to handler 'org.jasig.cas.web.ServiceValidateController@26a75b82'
 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Last-Modified value for [/cas/serviceValidate] is: -1
 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] DispatcherServlet with name 'cas' processing request for [/cas/serviceValidate]
 CasArgumentExtractor [DEBUG] Extractor generated service for:           https://geo.org.bo:443/j_spring_cas_security_check
 HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler [DEBUG] Attempting to resolve credentials for [callbackUrl: https://localhost:8443/receptor]
 HttpClient [DEBUG] Response Code did not match any of the acceptable response codes.  Code returned was 404
 AuthenticationManagerImpl [INFO] AuthenticationHandler: org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler failed to authenticate the user which provided the following credentials: [callbackUrl:      https://localhost:8443/receptor]
 ServiceValidateController [ERROR] TicketException generating ticket for: [callbackUrl: https://localhost:8443/receptor]
 org.jasig.cas.ticket.TicketCreationException: error.authentication.credentials.bad
at      org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:291)
```

Answer (score 6):

This error indicates that the CAS server is trying to (directly) connect to the client application to deliver a Proxy Granting Ticket (PGT). The url of `https://localhost:8443/receptor` is what is being tried, and the app is returning a 404-Not Found.

If your client application doesn't need to log into other CAS services on the users behalf, then you don't need proxying. Troubleshooting PGTs is more difficult than standard CAS 1.0, CAS 2.0, and SAML 1.1 protocols.

If you want to use Proxy tickets, then you might check https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Using+the+CAS+Client+3.1+with+Spring+Security

If you don't need Proxy tickets, then you might check http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html