# ServiceValidateController [ERROR] TicketException generating ticket for

Tags: spring-security, cas

I have an error with Cas when i try login, the logs fron the error are the next, i've self signed certificate and already add these to my keystore and and the keystore to the cacerts
thx for the help

These is the log from CAS

```
ServiceValidateController [ERROR] TicketException generating ticket for: [callbackUrl: https://localhost:8443/receptor]
org.jasig.cas.ticket.TicketCreationException: error.authentication.credentials.bad
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:291)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.ServiceValidateController.handleRequestInternal(ServiceValidateController.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilterInternal(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: error.authentication.credentials.bad
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.BadCredentialsAuthenticationException.<clinit>(BadCredentialsAuthenticationException.java:25)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl.authenticate(AuthenticationManagerImpl.java:113)
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:262)
    ... 26 more
```

These is the log from Ldap

```
geobolivia slapd[3024]: conn=1003 op=3 SRCH base="ou=users,dc=geobolivia,dc=gob,dc=bo" scope=2 deref=3 filter="(uid=geobolivia)"
geobolivia slapd[3024]: conn=1003 op=3 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
geobolivia slapd[3024]: conn=1003 op=4 SRCH base="ou=users,dc=geobolivia,dc=gob,dc=bo" scope=2 deref=3 filter="(uid=_cas_stateful_)"
geobolivia slapd[3024]: conn=1003 op=4 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
```

And these is the log from Security-proxy

```
ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl [INFO] No Proxy Ticket found for 
FilterBasedLdapUserSearch [DEBUG] Searching for user 'geobolivia', with user search [ searchFilter: '(uid={0})', searchBase: 'ou=users', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
AbstractContextSource [DEBUG] Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://localhost:389/dc=geobolivia,dc=gob,dc=bo'
SpringSecurityLdapTemplate [DEBUG] Searching for entry in under DN 'dc=geobolivia,dc=gob,dc=bo', base = 'ou=users', filter = '(uid={0})'
ProviderManager [DEBUG] Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
LdapAuthenticationProvider [DEBUG] Processing authentication request for user: _cas_stateful_
FilterBasedLdapUserSearch [DEBUG] Searching for user '_cas_stateful_', with user search [ searchFilter: '(uid={0})', searchBase: 'ou=users', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
AbstractContextSource [DEBUG] Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://localhost:389/dc=geobolivia,dc=gob,dc=bo'
SpringSecurityLdapTemplate [DEBUG] Searching for entry in under DN 'dc=geobolivia,dc=gob,dc=bo', base = 'ou=users', filter = '(uid={0})'
2013-08-29 18:29:15 CasAuthenticationFilter [DEBUG] Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
2013-08-29 18:29:15 CasAuthenticationFilter [DEBUG] Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
CasAuthenticationFilter [DEBUG] Delegating to authentication failure handlerorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@1e6ba8ee
SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler [DEBUG] No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository [DEBUG] SecurityContext is empty or anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter [DEBUG] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to: [CAS credentials bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489609/cas-credential-band)

Basically CAS is trying to call the client app because it is trying to deliver a PGT, but the client app isn't answering on the callback url.